# Mercurial: How to get rid of "warning: xxxx uses revlog format 0"?

Tags: mercurial

After working on a small project versioned with Hg for a while, I've verified the local and the central Mercurial repositories today. Locally I've got no errors or warning and "repository uses revlog format 1". In the central repository however I get

```
repository uses revlog format 1
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
warning: `x' uses revlog format 0
warning: `xx' uses revlog format 0
warning: `xxx' uses revlog format 0
...
```

(13 warnings of this type in total). Can I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: It seems that you have a *very* old repo. When you get no *errors* form `hg verify`, you can clone it and use the clone instead of the current one.

Comment: @Rudi, it would be great if your made your answers actual answers instead of comments.  A lot of folks give questions that show zero answers on the front page priority, but this one already had a great answer from you.  Also, if the asker gets what s/he needs from a comment it's less likely they'll come back to pick another answer later, which skews the incentive structure.

Comment: @Ry4an I don't make answers when I'm blindly guessing. I nether find about the `clone --pull` not the convert approach, so giving an answer saying do `hg clone` on the server would have been wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you clone a repo with `--pull` it will be recreated as the newest sort the version of Mercurial you're running can read/write.  Without `--pull` hardlinks are used to the old data files.

So **on the server** run:

```
hg clone --pull existingrepo newrepo
mv existingrepo was-existingrepo
mv newrepo existingrepo
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've also found another way. I've converted the repository from Hg to Hg using [Convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension). Repository now seems to have format 1, all files.

Comment: I would be careful with this.  Convert can change revision hashes, though I imagine it won't if you don't change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success creating a clone of the error-ridden repository at the point of the error and then pulling the contents of the error-ridden repository into the new clone.

Assuming the error starts at revision 170:

```
hg clone -r 170 damagedRepo newRepo
cd newRepo
hg pull ../damagedRepo
```